# I need help understanding why my javascript code is not working in one scenario vs another

Tags: javascript, function, scope

```
//var display = document.getElementById("display"); 
//var question1 = document.quiz.question1.value;                  
//var question2 = document.quiz.question2.value;   
//var question3 = document.quiz.question3.value;   
//var submit = document.getElementById("submit");          
//var correct = 0; 



function check() {   

var display = document.getElementById("display"); 
var question1 = document.quiz.question1.value;                  
var question2 = document.quiz.question2.value;   
var question3 = document.quiz.question3.value;   
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");          
var correct = 0;



if (question1 == "Asmara" || question1 == "asmara") {           
    correct++;     
}  

if(question2 == "Lisbon") {        
    correct++;   
}

if(question3 == "Trump") { 
    correct++;  
}

alert("You got " + correct + "/3 correct!");
```

}

This is my code and whenever I run it with my variables inside the function it works, but when I run it with the variables outside (globally) it does not seem to work. I am new to javascript and any advice is appreciated! Also note that I am calling this function from an html page using an event.

Comment: I expect your page hasn't fully loaded to allow you to use vars outside of the function (but the elements would be ready by the time the event is fired). There are ways to solve that issue, but that's the most likely reason. Add the code/call to the code to just before the </body> tag.

Comment: Will try that...thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
var display = document.getElementById("display"); 
var question1 = document.quiz.question1.value;                  
var question2 = document.quiz.question2.value;   
var question3 = document.quiz.question3.value;   
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");          
var correct = 0; 



function check(display, question1, question2, question3, submit, correct) {   
if (question1 == "Asmara" || question1 == "asmara") {           
    correct++;     
}  

if(question2 == "Lisbon") {        
    correct++;   
}

if(question3 == "Trump") { 
    correct++;  
}

alert("You got " + correct + "/3 correct!");      
}
```

If i am not mistaken, you need to PASS your variables as arguments to the function. So wherever you're calling the function, change your function call to

```
check(display, question1, question2, question3, submit, correct)
```